# Springboot + springfox + swagger2 + swagger-ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

How can i access the generated swagger-ui.html ? Or index.html I cant seem to find this file in my project. Aghhhh!

Comment: Please paste some code so that we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Also, have you downloaded the swagger-dist from github? Depending on the version you want to use, it will be a link like this - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

Comment: I just want to access the files generated in webjars. No code will explain my problem.

Comment: This is exactly what i ended up doing. I thought there would be a better way to override swagger-ui.html

Comment: Please add it as an answer to your own question so that it can help other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling the swagger-ui dist files from git

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

I placed them inside public directory and modified swagger-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

For the library setup which you have mentioned, the following will be the URL to access the UI -

```
PROTOCOL://HOST:PORT/CONTEXT_NAME/swagger-ui.html

Eg: http://localhost:8083/xms/swagger-ui.html
```